Send a message to agent filtering through parameter (anylogic)
Im working on a anylogic model. I have two agents that need to communicate. Firms and Unis. Firms have a parameter called size (int, uniform_discr 0,1).
In the Uni statechart I want it to send a message on an entry action but only to firms with size = 1.
I used the following on the Uni statechart (tried both):
   this.sendToRandom("cresci2", filter(Firm, size == 1));   

   this.sendToRandom("cresci2", randomWhere( firms, p ->p,size =1));


When the agent Univ enters fase3,it should send the message to agents Firms to move to TRL3 (in blue)

I get two erros sayinf firms  cannot be resolved to a variable. I tried with Firm, main.firms, firms... any hints?
"Description: firms cannot be resolved to a variable. Location: Lucia25Giu24/Univ/fase3 - State"

pls learn about how to navigate your model hierarchy: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to
